# how to use javascript to get jsf table data?

Tags: javascript, jsf, datatable

I have jsf datatable populated from backing bean ArrayList. Now I need to compare values with the values in one column of my table, how can i do this?

my datatable:

```
<t:dataTable var="tabl"
rowIndexVar="rownum" 
id="data" 
value="#{bean.sortedList}"
>
```

..........
the column i want to compare data:

```
<t:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:commandLink>
            <h:outputText  value="sortedList"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
     <f:verbatim>&nbsp;</f:verbatim>
    <h:inputText value="#{tabl.numbers}"
                id="numbers">
    </h:inputText>
</t:column>
```

my table structure:

```
<tbody id="myForm:data:tbody_element">
<tr>
...
<td>&#160;<input id="myForm:data:0:workAreaNumberU" name="myForm:data:0:workAreaNumberU" type="text" value="0001" size="4" onkeyup="value_altered(0);"></td>
</tr>
....
<tr>
...
<td>&#160;<span id="_idJsp1:data:1:workAreaNumber">0104</span></td>
...
</tr>
</tbody>
```

finally solved in this way (base on my table structure)

```
var table = document.getElementById("myForm:data:tbody_element");
var new_wa;
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    var new_wa_box = document.getElementById("myForm:data:" + i + ":workAreaNumberU");
    if( new_wa_box != null ) {
        new_wa = new_wa_box.value;
    }else{
        new_wa_box = document.getElementById("myForm:data:" + i + ":workAreaNumber");
        new_wa = new_wa_box.innerHTML;
        }
    alert("row new_wa_box = "+new_wa);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a JSF problem. It's not different from when using plain HTML. JavaScript doesn't work with the JSF source code, but with its generated HTML output only (as you can see by rightclick and *View Source* in browser). Your concrete mistake is that you used `element.innerHTML` which returns the entire HTML content of the `<td>` instead of getting the `<input>` element from the `<td>` first and then its `value` attribute.

This should give you the value of the first `<input>` element of the `<td>`, prechecks omitted for brevity:

```
var value = col.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
```

I only wonder the usefulness of doing this all in JavaScript instead of in JSF.

Comment: the tag name should be inputText and this is not working. and also, client side validation is different from server side. unless you know how to break the lifecycle and update the value of properties in managed beans

Comment: Open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source*. Do you see a `<h:inputText>`? No, you see only `<input type="text">`. This is also exactly what JavaScript is seeing. This is exactly what I'm trying to tell you in my answer. If it doesn't work for you, well then you've left details out of your question. But you should now realize that JavaScript does not see the JSF source code as it is in webserver, but it only sees its generated HTML as the webbrowser has retrieved.

Comment: oh ok, so I have to use input instead. i have this on my page : <td class="">&#160;<input id="myForm:data:11:workAreaNumberU" name="_idJsp1:data:11:workAreaNumberU" type="text" value="0012" size="4"></td> the value is the one I need. the error msg is 'getElementsByTagName(...)[0].value' is null or not an object

Comment: You need to replace `col.innerHTML` in your original code by that line.

Comment: I just updated my question, yes I removed that line. i get output [object] if I remove '.value'.

Comment: Apparently you've some columns where is no such input element. You'd need to check that first before getting the value. E.g. `var input = col.getElementsByTagName("input")[0]; if (input) { alert (input.value); }`. Or just use fixed column indexes instead of going through all columns.